# DataTable - Column 1 cells ( use values from array ), column 2 cells ( use custom html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to create a **datatable** wherein my **first column** values come from an **array** and **second and other columns** contains **custom html ( select boxes, inputs etc)**.I have used datatable **before** but that time i was reading data from json ( for all columns ) like this:

```
    function basketTable(data){
        topTable = $('#at-top-100').dataTable({
             //layout of data table 
             "dom": 'Tlfrtip',
             "bInfo" : false,
             "bDestroy":true,
             "bFilter" : false,
             "responsive":true,
             "aaData" : data,
             "aoColumns": [
                         { "mData": "Ap" },
                         { "mData": "Dp" },
                         { "mData": "A"},
                         { "mData": "S"},
                         { "mData": "S"},
                     ],
             "iDisplayLength": 10,
             "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "",
                    "sSearchPlaceholder" : "Search..",
                    "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
              }
        });
}
```

Any insight on how i can achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "mrender" function and place any html you want to render per cell in the function.

You can also access the properties of the object in the row if you want to use them in your display.
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

```
function basketTable(data){
        topTable = $('#at-top-100').dataTable({
             //layout of data table 
             "dom": 'Tlfrtip',
             "bInfo" : false,
             "bDestroy":true,
             "bFilter" : false,
             "responsive":true,
             "aaData" : data,
             "aoColumns": [
                         { "mData": "Ap" },
                         { "mData": "Dp" },
                         { "mData": "A"},
                         { "mData": "S"},
                         { "mData": "S",
                           "mRender": function(data,type,full)
                           {
                             return '<input type="text" value="Scanners and Scales"/>'
                           }
                     ],
             "iDisplayLength": 10,
             "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "",
                    "sSearchPlaceholder" : "Search..",
                    "sLengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
              }
        });
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot...i'll try this n get back to you!!